# How to set UIButton in expandable tableViewCell with pattern Image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

In my table view, I want to set pattern Image to the Custom button in expandable cell in each row of my table view.

which method I can use for it?

please help me.

Comment: Please click on "edit" below your question and add your code so far. See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Generally at the appropriate time you should call:

```
[myButton setImage:image forState:state]
```

The appropriate time might be in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, or `tableView:willDisplayCell:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[yourbutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image name"]]];
```